# Link not active in next.js even when I am on the page

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap

I am trying to get a link to have the `active` class when clicked in `next.js` and `react-bootstrap`. Upon page load, the currently active route's link is not given the active class. When I click on the link after page load, then it is given the `active` class. I suspect that this has something to do with server-side rendering. Here is my code:

```
const Navigation = () => (
    <Navbar bg="warning" variant="light" collapseOnSelect expand="lg">
        <Link passHref href="/">
            <Navbar.Brand>...</Navbar.Brand>
        </Link>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
                <Link href="/">
                    <Nav.Link href="/" as="a">
                        Home
                    </Nav.Link>
                </Link>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
);

export default Navigation;
```

Upon page load:
[image: link upon page load]
After clicking link manually:
[image: link after clicking manually]

Is there a way to make the link highlighted on the server (without a hacky solution)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, so far there is no built-in feature like that whether in NextJS or react-bootstrap.

The example below is not a hacky solution, it is the best practice introduced by NextJS.

You need to use a class to show an active link, then have this function to check if the current url is same as the url in next/router:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Link from 'next/link'
import React, { Children } from 'react'

const ActiveLink = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  const { asPath } = useRouter()
  const child = Children.only(children)
  const childClassName = child.props.className || ''

  // pages/index.js will be matched via props.href
  // pages/about.js will be matched via props.href
  // pages/[slug].js will be matched via props.as
  const className =
    asPath === props.href || asPath === props.as
      ? `${childClassName} active`.trim()
      : childClassName

  return (
    <Link {...props}>
      {React.cloneElement(child, {
        className: className || null,
      })}
    </Link>
  )
}

ActiveLink.propTypes = {
  activeClassName: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default ActiveLink
```

Then in your component:

```
const Navigation = () => (
    <Navbar bg="warning" variant="light" collapseOnSelect expand="lg">
        <Link passHref href="/">
            <Navbar.Brand>...</Navbar.Brand>
        </Link>
        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="responsive-navbar-nav" />
        <Navbar.Collapse id="responsive-navbar-nav">
            <Nav className="ml-auto">
                <Link href="/">
                    <ActiveLink href="/">
                        <Nav.Link href="/" as="a">
                            Home
                        </Nav.Link>
                    </ActiveLink>
                </Link>
            </Nav>
        </Navbar.Collapse>
    </Navbar>
);

export default Navigation;
```

[source](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/active-class-name)

Comment: Second code (the one starting with `const Navigation = () => (`) piece is completely off

Comment: Active Link component works fine except if you are using Nextjs framework it would throw an error regarding the misusage of functional component under the Link component of NextJS. You can read more on this issue on offial [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#if-the-child-is-a-function-component).

I got this error using this solutions.

`Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of 'Link'.`

I've already read the solution, but can't get rid of the error.

Comment: @Ravenwits did you find a way to get rid of this error? I am having the same issue with cloneElement nested in next/link.